# Android Home Screen Widget with SDK version 11 or above Only

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-widget

I am working with the application minimum sdk version 3. I want the app to support Home Screen widget with OS 3.0(sdk - 11) or above only. i.e. User with OS 3.0 or above only should be displayed in widget. How to do the same ?

I already asked one more question let me know if its possible too.
[How to get Number of records displayed in RemoteView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12559154/206809)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**
Publish 2 APKs:

- One with `android:minSdkVersion="11"` in your manifest and with your widget implementation
- The other one with `android:minSdkVersion="3"`in your manifest and no widget implementation

**Solution 2:**
Keep minSdk 3 (`android:minSdkVersion="3"`) and check the SDK version in both methods `onUpdate` and `onReceive` of the class that extends AppWidgetProvider. Do the job only if `Build.VERSION.SKD_INT >= 11`.
In the same way, if you have a [App Widget Configuration Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring), do the following in `onCreate()`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.widget_error_cannot_be_installed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}
```

Just keep in mind that users with OS<3.0 will see the widget in their widget gallery but will not be able to add it. So you might show a Toast something like "Your Android OS version is too low to add widget".

Let us know if you find any other solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same type of issue.

**Solution:**

if android os version 2.2 or lower then make static list of your data.

else you have to implement listview and set all contain.

If you find any trouble then let me know.

Answer (score -1):

1) You can check OS version with [Build.VERSION.SDK_INT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html), compare it to version codes defined in [Build.VERSION_CODES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html).

2) Keep in mind that on OSes before 2.0 (If i remember it correctly) ClassLoaders are very angry about any 'not supported' classes or methods mentioned in any methods of a loaded class, even if you never actually call these methods. So be sure you don't import anything not available on 1.5 in classes that will be used in 1.5 .

Comment: but the issue is that.. by doing so there will be a widget in the list on os below 3.0.. I dont want this

Comment: Well that's the point of checking the OS version - if it's above 3.0 you remove the widget (or otherwise, add it if version is below and turn it off by default).